# Multiple inclusion of header file error in C

Tags: c, conditional-compilation

So I have a header file let's say "header.h" which is protected as follows:

```
#ifndef __HEADER1_H
#define __HEADER1_H
//type and function def 
typedef struct
{
  float r; //process noise
  float k; //process gain
}state_t;

int get_state(state_t* state, float b);

#endif
```

Now I have two other headers which I defined as follows:

```
 #ifdef __HEADER2_H
 #include "header.h"
//function def
 #endif
```

Second header:

```
#ifdef __HEADER3_H
//function
//the reason it is done this way is for cnditional compiling such that if the caller  

//defines __HEADER3_H t this file won't be included.
#include "header.h"
#endif
```

Now as I suspected the compiler complained that types and functions defined in header.h were not detected in the source implementation of header2 and header3. So I included header.h in the source files as well. Now the linker is complaining functions that are defined in header.h are multiply defined.
My understanding was since the header.h is protected by ifndef it will only be included once so I don't see the problem.
here is the error that I am getting:

```
Symbol get_state multiply defined(by kalman.o and dsp.o)
```

Is there any chance that I am doing something unusally wrong?

Comment: Yep, see the comments below -- you've got several things wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the second and third code segments??

Comment: I'm thinking at this point that it might make sense to paste in the actual header.h file (or at least enough to show the top, bottom, and at least one item the compiler complains about) -- to avoid further typos from making it impossible to answer in a helpful manner.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to avoid compiling if there __HEADER2_H and __HEADER3_H are not defined.

Comment: The "multiply defined" error does not mean you are delcaring the function twice (which is what multiple inclusions of header1.h, as you've pasted it here, would do). It means you have implemented the function twice - which could mean you implemented it in the header file, causing both kalman.c and dsp.c to implement it, or could mean both of those source files actually contain the implementation (which is one too many).

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef __HEADER1_H
#define __HEADER_H
```

The problem is your guard (`__HEADER_H`) is different from what you are checking for (`__HEADER1_H`). Make these both the same value.

Comment: And you don't show the necessary `#define` in your second and third headers.  Your second and third headers use `#ifdef` rather than `#ifndef`,, and don't have the required `#define`. Also, identifiers starting with `_` are reserved to the implementation; these aren't likely to cause problems, but you should use identifiers like `HEADER1_H`.

Comment: I made a typing mistake here. In my code I used __HEADER1.h. But good point Keith. I modiied that in my code although the error still shows up.

Answer (score 1):

The typical "guard" for a header file is:

```
myheader.h:

#ifndef _MYHEADER
#define _MYHEADER
<do stuff>
#endif
```

*Optionally* where myheader.h is included, you can do:

```
#ifndef _MYHEADER
#include "myheader.h"
#endif
```

This is *optional* and basically is only to improve compile performance.